# Achieving one-to-many relationship in QGIS custom forms

Tags: qgis, postgresql, one-to-many

My PostgreSQL database has **ElectricLine** geometry table which has one-to-many relationship with **ElectricLineMaterial** non-geometry (attribute only) table. This PostgreSQL table added as layer in QGIS 2.0.1. When the user add/edit an ElectricLine, he should have ability to add one or more ElectricLineMaterial records against to that geometry.

Can I achieve this requirement via **Custom QGIS Forms**? In other words, I want to have an "Add Electric Line Material" button in the form to add many materials against the current adding/editing electric-line.

*Note: I am new to QGIS and learning QT Designer.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QGIS 2.1's [Relations](http://blog.vitu.ch/10112013-1201/qgis-relations) handles the relationship data in QGIS in a excellent way.

*Note: 2.1 is a dev version, 2.2 will be the release version.*

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Rather than build a solution yourself, there is a plugin you can use.  [The Data Driven Input Mask](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DataDrivenInputMask/) plugin can handle data entry for one-to-many situations.  It can also handle constraints, foreign key relationships, etc in your Postgres database.

Comment: I also tried it out, but I got the error "cannot import name QtSql". Anybody else have that problem?

Comment: I have installed the plugin to QGIS and added relationships between PostgreSql tables. But there are no changes in the UI. How to enable this plugin functionality in the UI?